# iOS: Facebook Login error

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, authentication

There is always an error when trying to login via my ios app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    // Align the button in the center horizontally
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 25);
    loginView.delegate = self;
//loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"];
    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes", @"user_events",  @"user_videos", @"user_subscriptions", @"user_photos"];
    loginView.publishPermissions = @[@"manage_friendlists", @"manage_notifications", @"photo_upload", @"manage_pages", @"publish_stream", @"read_friendlists", @"read_mailbox", @"read_requests", @"read_stream", @"share_item", @"video_upload"];

    [self.view addSubview:loginView];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession:
>   Publish permissions were requested without specifying an audience; use
>   FBSessionDefaultAudienceJustMe, FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends, or
>   FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone'

What can i do to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the **`defaultAudience`**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) FBSessionDefaultAudience defaultAudience;
```

The default audience to use, if publish permissions are requested at login time.

Add:

```
loginView.defaultAudience = FBSessionDefaultAudienceJustMe;
```

Or any from the following:
`FBSessionDefaultAudienceJustMe`, `FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends`, or `FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone`

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLoginView/